# Bluemix NodeRed SQL

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I am using NodeRed to collect data from a CC2650 SensorTag and store it in a SQL database. 
The SensorTag is connected to my phone through the app and the data is pushed to the cloud. My NodeRed application collects this data then stores it to my SQL. However I have found the system will disconnect and is unable to monitor the data for long periods of time. I have two sensortags connected and the data stream seems to randomly stop. I believe it is due to a loss in connection between NodeRed and SQL but am unsure. Is anyone else running a similar programme facing these problems?

The data will appear in the NodeRED debug screen and get uploaded to the SQL database in the table. As the data is being sent I can see each point being uploaded as I refresh the table however the upload is not consistent and will sometimes stop uploading to the SQL table despite still being displayed on the debug. So far I have not seen any pattern the data will stop randomly for no clear reason. I have been able to refresh the system and deploy it again to try and get it running again however this is not always successful and only a temporary solution.

Comment: This is not a good question for Stackoverflow as it stands. Please list what steps you have taken that lead you to believe it is a drop in connection to the database and what you have already tried to remedy the problem.

Comment: I contacted the maintainers of the sqldb node for Node-RED because I could reproduce it. Someone is looking into it.

Comment: Stay tuned, there is progress

Comment: the node for interfacing with the sqldb and dashdb service has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use CloudantSQL instead of SQL,since it stores the entire message in json format and then you can extract the data you need precisely and store it in NO-SQL db later.

The cloudant node is good than normal SQL node,since it just stores in JSON format ,whatever data comes in without any lag or delay !!

Comment: I had some trouble using CloudantSQL format. Is there any tutorials or user guide?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in the [Node-RED node interfacing with the sqldb and dashDB](http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-nodes-cf-sqldb-dashdb) services. It had a problem with keeping long opened connections stable over time (in the Node-Red context). The code has been updated.

Contrary to the suggestion of using Cloudant, use sqldb. :) Depending whether you want to store the entire JSON message, only parts of it, and how the data will be used later on in terms of queries and other applications, the relational format may make sense.